# Its possible to getDateTime from database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have problem with DATABASE in android because my DATABASE is have like 2 months later from now, and i can't make something like this with query:

```
 public LiveTvProgram currentPlayedProgram(int channelID) {
    LiveTvProgram program = new LiveTvProgram();
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String selectQuery = " SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PROGRAMS + " WHERE " +
            TvContract.Programs.COLUMN_START_TIME_UTC_MILLIS + " < " + currentTime +
            " AND " + TvContract.Programs.COLUMN_END_TIME_UTC_MILLIS + " > " + currentTime + " AND "
            + TvContract.Programs.COLUMN_CHANNEL_ID + " = " + channelID;
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
    program = LiveTvProgram.fromCursor(timeDifference, cursor);
        cursor.close();
}

    return program;
}
```

So when i do like this i just got record with Today 00:00, and everthing is like this. Its not nessesary to do this, but i want ask for you, Is it possible to get time from database and do this?

Comment: are you trying to get the datetime of the database and return it to the application?

Comment: i cant call something like myDatabase.getTime or getDate

Comment: to get the current datetime you would want `DATETIME('now')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible but you have to Store in a proper format.

```
contentValues=null;
contentValues=new ContentValues();
cal=null;
cal=Calendar.getInstance();
currentDay=0;
currentDay=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, currentDay+Pl+1);
contentValues.put("callfromdate",cal.getTime().toString());
contentValues.put("type","Dll");
contentValues.put("days",String.valueOf(Dl));
cal=null;
cal=Calendar.getInstance();
currentDay=0;
currentDay=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, currentDay+Pl+Dl);
contentValues.put("calltodate",cal.getTime().toString());
```

Comment: Ok, but how to compare this with databse?

Comment: This is a dome first you have to store the Time and Date in database Then we Compare